# Start/Stop a function using pushbutton

Tags: button, arduino

I am trying to display the readings of LDR on my 0.96" Adafruit OLED. I have succeeded with obtaining that results.
Now I want to start the display of the reading only when I push the button and stop it once I push it again. This should go on a loop.
I tried to draft a code for that:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
int sensorPin = A0; // select the input pin for ldr
int sensorValue = 0;
boolean state = false;
int buttonpin;


#define OLED_RESET 4 // not used / nicht genutzt bei diesem Display
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

 char inChar;
 String string;


void setup()   { 

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  buttonpin = 2; //whatever pin your button is plugged into

  pinMode(buttonpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
 // initialize with the I2C addr 0x3C / mit I2C-Adresse 0x3c initialisieren
 display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  display.setTextColor(INVERSE); 
}

void loop()
{
  while (state == false) 
  {
     if (digitalRead(buttonpin) == HIGH)
     {
      display.clearDisplay();
      sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
      Serial.println(sensorValue); 
      display.setCursor(30,0); 
      display.setTextSize(1);
      display.print("LDR Reading:");
      display.setCursor(30,10); 
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.print(sensorValue);
      delay(500);           
      display.display(); 
      state = false; 
     }


   }
 }
```

But the screen starts displaying the results only when I keep the push button pressed continuously and when I release the button , the program halts with the last reading displayed on the screen.

I need the results as follows:

1st press: starts displaying readings
2nd press: screen should be blank. (display.clearDisplay() does that job)

I am unfamiliar with the usage of switch case in Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a Boolean to track the toggle state and a Boolean to keep the state of the button from the previous loop.  If the button goes from low to high between loop iterations then update the toggle Boolean,

```
toggle = !togggle
```

Base your condition for the display state then on the toggle instead of directly on the button.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?.. I am just a beginner. It would be kind of you if you could modify my code to add the toggle state.

Answer (score 1):

Thie is to elaborate on @shaunussain's answer.

Here is an exampole of a toggle:

Create a boolean variable : `bool toggle = false;` The variable state is at false at the beginning. Thus, the screen will start blank.

Then do something like this. This is just a logic.

If the button is pressed

`if( buttonPressed() ) {`

Change toggle's state. So if it was ON / true, it will change to OFF / false.

```
    toggle = !toggle;
```

Now, we wait until the button has been released, otherwise the code might go a little crazy! And then we close the brackets.

```
    while ( buttonPressed() );
}
```

---

Then in your loop, you will have a switch case. We start by innitializing the switch case.

```
switch( toggle ) {
```

Then we set up a case for when the toggle is on ON / true. 1 is true, 0 is false.

```
case  1 :
```

Then we write the code body.

```
    displayTextOnScreen();
```

Then we exit the switch case because `toggle` matched with our case.

```
    break;
```

Then, if we `toggle` isn't true or it is something else (because there was a glitch in the code), we will have a default case.

```
default:
```

In the default, we want the screen to be off, so if it isn't suppose to be on, or if there is a bug, it will be off. Then we will close the switch case and exit it because default is the last possible case in a switch case.

```
    display.clearDisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much, it helped me a lot. The code is working fine. Updated code :

```
    #include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
int sensorPin = A0; // select the input pin for ldr
int sensorValue = 0;
bool toggle = false;
int buttonpin;


#define OLED_RESET 4 // not used / nicht genutzt bei diesem Display
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

 char inChar;
 String string;


void setup()   { 

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  buttonpin = 2; 
  pinMode(buttonpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // initialize with the I2C addr 0x3C / mit I2C-Adresse 0x3c initialisieren
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  display.setTextColor(INVERSE); 
}

void loop()
{
     if (digitalRead(buttonpin) == HIGH)
     {
      toggle = !toggle;
      while(digitalRead(buttonpin) == HIGH);
     }
      switch( toggle )
         {

          case 1:
           display.clearDisplay();
            sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
            Serial.println(sensorValue); 
            display.setCursor(30,0); 
            display.setTextSize(1);
            display.print("LDR Reading:");
            display.setCursor(30,10); 
            display.setTextSize(2);
            display.print(sensorValue);
            delay(500);           

            break;

           case 0:
            display.clearDisplay(); 

            break;
           }
       display.display();



 }
```

Comment: Sweet glad you were able to make that concept actually work, didn't have any sample code handy to share but good you were able to take it from concept to implementation, interesting idea using the while loop to stay locked there until the button is released too.

Comment: Don't use case 0, use default. This is because if there is any bugs in the code, nothing will happen.